# Chrome Extension - Removed Elements Keeps Coming Back

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension that can remove elements after a page load.

Every time I scroll down in the target website (YouTube) and load more data to the list, the elements I already removed, keep showing up again. No idea how the target website works...

Try v1.0 `element.remove();`

Try v2.0 `element.parentElement.removeChild(element);`

I am procrastinating this problem for months and spend most of the last couple of days on it :/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I don't try to remove them, simply make them not "relevant" in the DOM but still present as a child of the parent element (the list container)!

```
element.innerHTML = "";
element.style.width = "0px";
element.style.height = "0px";
element.style.margin = "0px";
element.style.padding = "0px";
```

No idea if it's a rare problem that I am the only one the encountered it, but of it helps someone that's great!